# Heartbleed: dist-upgrade didn't fix it

Tags: upgrade, updates

Sorry for my bad English.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-60-virtual x86_64).

In an attempt to fix Heartbleed, I first ran `apt-get update`, then `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

It went all OK, so I thought that that security issue was fixed.

But `openssl version -a` outputs:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Sat Feb  1 22:14:33 UTC 2014
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(8x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM

OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

I have already rebooted the server (I had to replace `sysvinit` with `upstart` after dist-upgrade, otherwise I couldn't reboot).

After rebooting, `apt-get dist-upgrade` outputs the following:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  upstart
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sysvinit
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnih-dbus1 libnih1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Well, according to that output, there is nothing ssl-related left to upgrade. But `openssl version -a` keeps outputting the same old February build.

So, my question is why is my system still running the old build of openssl?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You would need to show us the `apt-cache policy openssl` output, otherwise we have no way to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue!

For some reason, `apt-get update` wasn't getting aware of the new security packages (although Ubuntu security repository is correctly listed in my sources.list).

What I had to do was to manually download the following deb files, and then install them manually.

List of packages I had to download and install

### 64 Bit

- openssl: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12_amd64.deb
- libssl1.0.0: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12_amd64.deb
- libssl-dev: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12_amd64.deb

### 32 Bit

- http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12_i386.deb
- http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.1c-3ubuntu2.7_i386.deb
- http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1c-3ubuntu2.7_i386.deb

The following command will install a manually downloaded deb package:

`sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb`

After installing all the 3 packages and rebooting the server, the problem is now fixed!

[image]
(Output of http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/.)

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation, and I've found a simpler solution (for 12.04 LTS):

sudo apt-get install openssl=1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12 libssl1.0.0=1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12 libssl-dev=1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12

This asks me to DOWNGRADE these package, and by answering yes, the packages are updated.

It seems that openssl packages from a newer ubuntu distribution (quantal or something) are sneaked into my installation when I tried to get some package from the distribution. Since the security repos in sources.list are pointed to precise, the packages from newer distributions cannot be updated by apt-get dist-upgrade.

Comment: Solid, worth mentioning you have to do apt-get update first.